# Export SVG with some lines of text in PDF

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, export, pdf-generation

I have developed a service that allows users to create a SVG diagram (I've used d3.js), also together with the diagram some text content is created using ace.js.

Summarizing I have :

- SVG Content generated by D3
- Text Content generated by ACE Editor

In particular, I have been offering this service to client using node.js .

Do you know any ways to create a PDF which includes both SVG picture and text ?

EDIT:
I can accept both client and server-side solution to address my issue.

Answer (score 0):

SVG file format allows you to define text elements ( and  tags) and to apply text styles. In the case a regular SVG-to-PDF converter, probably [Apache Batic](http://apache.org/batik/), would be sufficient.

If you want to combine SVG and HTML tags/texts in the same document  - you need to look for a HTML-to-PDF converter with SVG graphics support. I would recommend to try [PhantomJS (free)](http://phantomjs.org) and [PD4ML (commercial)](http://pd4ml.com/cookbook/svg_to_pdf_conversion.htm)

If you really need to mix SVG tags with a raw text, an enclosing of an entire document content to <pre> and </pre> tags and a passing the result to HTML-to-PDF converter should do the trick.